# monaca タブ移動したページでmodalが使用できない

Tags: monaca

monacaでタブでpage2に移動した際にボタンを押すとmodalを表示したいのですが
http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-modal.html
こちらを参考に入れてみたのですが全く動きません・・

ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script>
    ons.bootstrap()

    $(document.body).on("pageinit", '#my-page', function() {
      $("#show-modal", this).click(function() {
        modal.show();
        setTimeout('modal.hide()', 2000);
      });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
                <ons-tabbar-item page="navigator.html" active="true">
                    <div class="my-icon"><img class="nav_img" src="img/icon01.png" alt="HOME" width="36" /></div>
                </ons-tabbar-item>
                <ons-tabbar-item page="page2_in.html">
                    <div class="my-icon"><img class="nav_img" src="img/icon02.png" alt="ITEM" width="36" /></div>
                </ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="navigator.html">
        <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html">
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="page2_in.html">
        <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page2.html">
        </ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>

    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<ons-page id="my-page">

<ons-toolbar fixed-style>
    <div class="center">ITEM</div>
</ons-toolbar>

  <div ons-loading-placeholder="start.html">
     アプリケーションの読み込みを行っています...
  </div>
  <ons-template id="start.html">

    <ons-button id="show-modal" modifier="light">Open Modal</ons-button>

　</ons-template>

<ons-modal var="modal">
  <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
  <br>
  <br> Please wait.
  <br>Closing in 2 seconds.
</ons-modal>

</ons-page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ons-loading-placeholder`属性の要素と関連部分(`ons-template`)を削除すると動作します。
※一部JavaScriptも修正してあります。
※jQueryコンポーネントは有効。

> Onsen UIが必要なフレームワーク一式の読み込みを完了するまで、読み込み中画面を表示することができます。これはOnsen UIをWebアプリケーションで使用する場合に便利です。ons-loading-placeholder属性を持つ要素は、Onsen UIの読み込みが完了した時点で、ons-loading-placeholder要素が参照するテンプレートに置き換わります。

まずは、一つ一つの機能を把握して使用すべきだと思います。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script>
    ons.bootstrap()
    ons.ready(function() {
        $(document.body).on("pageinit", "#my-page", function() {
            $("#show-modal", this).click(function() {
                modal.show();
                setTimeout("modal.hide()", 2000);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-tabbar var="tabbar">
        <ons-tabbar-item page="navigator.html" active="true">
            <div class="my-icon">
                <img class="nav_img" src="img/icon01.png" alt="HOME" width="36" />
            </div>
        </ons-tabbar-item>
        <ons-tabbar-item page="page2_in.html">
            <div class="my-icon">
                <img class="nav_img" src="img/icon02.png" alt="ITEM" width="36" />
            </div>
        </ons-tabbar-item>
    </ons-tabbar>
    <ons-template id="navigator.html">
        <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page1.html"></ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>
    <ons-template id="page2_in.html">
        <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator" page="page2.html"></ons-navigator>
    </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<ons-page id="my-page">
    <ons-toolbar fixed-style>
        <div class="center">ITEM</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-button id="show-modal" modifier="light">Open Modal</ons-button>
    <ons-modal var="modal">
        <ons-icon icon="ion-load-c" spin="true"></ons-icon>
        <br>
        <br>Please wait. 
        <br>Closing in 2 seconds. 
    </ons-modal>
</ons-page>
```

Comment: 参考になりました！ありがとうございました！